# Find And Replace in a subfolder/TXT From CSV File using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, find, subdirectory

I listed all the find and replacement entry in csv. my requirement is to perform find and replacement in sub folder for all the text file.

here is how csv file looks:

```
csvfind_replacement.csv
xxx   ;yyy
111   ;AAA
222   ;BBB
333   ;CCC
```

operation:

1. open text files from subfolder one by one
2. find xxx and replace yyy

> ```
> import os
> import csv
> # CSV file with find and replace format
> with open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\csvfind_replacement.csv','rb') as csvfind_replacement.csv:
>     reader = csv.reader(csvfind_replacement, delimiter=';')
>
> # walk through all file 
>
> for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test'):
>   for name in files:
>       file = open(“name”,”w”) 
>           for row in reader:
>               replace(row[], column[])
>      file.close
> ```

Above is my incomplete/non working code. Just wondering if there is any input to complete find and replacement tasks from CSV for all the subfolders.

Comment: So, you want to replace every occurrence of "xxx" by "yyy", every occurrence of "111" by "222" and so, for each of the files?   If so, just use `str.replace()`

Comment: I'm missing a concrete problem here‽ What exactly are you asking? That code doesn't even pass the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.  The `csv.reader` is an iterator, so once you iterate over it, it's empty.  In the code below, I recreated the reader on every pass through the loop, but it would be better to make a list:

listReader = list(reader)

once, outside the loop, and then you could iterate over the list on each pass through the loop.  I'll leave it to you to do that.

I changed your CSV file to look like this:

```
cat csvfind_replacement.csv 
xxx;yyy
111;AAA
222;BBB
333;CCC
```

Otherwise, the spaces before the semicolon are part of the search text, which I assumed you didn't want.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import csv

fn = 'csvfind_replacement.csv'
os.chdir(r'/Users/saul/Desktop')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('csvTest'):
    for name in files:
       print(name)
       if not (name.endswith('txt') ):
           continue
       text = open(os.path.join(root, name)).read()
       print("Before:")
       print(text)
       csvfile = open(fn, newline='')
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')  
       for row in reader:
            if row:
                text=text.replace(row[0], row[1])
       print('\nAfter')
       print(text)
       file = open(name,'w')
       file.write(text)
       file.close
       csvfile.close()
```

my csvTest folder has two text files, text1.txt and test2.txt, and also a file named .DS_Store that MacOS creates.  It has a subfolder sub, with one text file named test3.txt.

Here are my test results:

```
.DS_Store
test1.txt
Before:
line 1 xxx
line 2 111
line 3 222
line 4 333


After
line 1 yyy
line 2 AAA
line 3 BBB
line 4 CCC

test2.txt
Before:
line 1 111
line 2 222222
line 3 abcd
line 4 xxx
line 5 333111xxx


After
line 1 AAA
line 2 BBBBBB
line 3 abcd
line 4 yyy
line 5 CCCAAAyyy

test3.txt
Before:
line 1 xxxxxxx
line 2 111111
line 3 222111
line 4 3333


After
line 1 yyyyyyx
line 2 AAAAAA
line 3 BBBAAA
line 4 CCC3
```

Comment: Thank you for the big help!

Comment: It was my pleasure.